# this code works perfectly if i don't add the module name (myApp).. once i add the module name, the angularjs stop executing

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model='name'>{{name}}
    </div>
        <!-- Angular JS-->
    <script src="../vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i'm trying out angular for the first time, and i encounter this error

Comment: Because it's looking for a `myApp` AngularJS module, but you don't have one. Did you forget a `<script>` tag referencing your AngularJS code?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your AngularJS code? It needs the app name declaring in the modules otherwise it will error as its referencing something that doesnt exist.

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

Comment: i did that and it still doesn't work.. i had to reference angular.min.js at top of the page

Answer (score 0):

i've fixed it.. i had to referenced the angular.min.js file at the top of the page